# fórmula do Excell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho três listas de pontuações, cuja primeira e a segunda variam de 5 a 10 e a terceira de 0 a 150. Ao fazer a soma dos dados, obviamente as variações da terceira serão maiores que nas duas primeiras.
Assim eu procuro uma formula que primeiro determine o intervalo entre os valores iniciais para que depois a partir de estipular um teto de 10 e um mínimo de 5, e possa aplicar o mesmo valor percentual dos intervalos inicias e assim não permitir uma variação grande em relação aos primeiros valores e não tirar o mérito impostos pelas diferenças da terceira.

Qual a minha finalidade?
- São duas listas de notas de provas de alunos que valem 10.
- Uma lista de notas de trabalhos que valem 150.
Gostaria de somar todas, dando peso de 33% para cada, permitindo manter o mérito dos intervalos de todas elas e que as variações da ultima sejam tão relevantes em relação a insignificância das variações das duas maiores.

Será que é possível?

Comment: Edite a questão para adicionar o código que você já usou para tentar resolver o problema. Indique também se você deseja uma solução com VBA ou através de *interop* com .NET/OOXML.

Comment: Por favor, leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/75104), [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e [Seja mais específico na pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104). Se você puder adicionar um exemplo pequeno com imagens de como estão seus dados no momento e como deseja o resultado, ajudaria a entender melhor o problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Para transformar a terceira lista na escala equivalente das duas primeiras, você pode usar a seguinte fórmula:

`ValorLista3/30+5`

Tomando a tabela abaixo como exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As fórmulas poderiam ser assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Fernando.
É isso! 
A média das duas deve ser zero, pois se tirou menos que 5 foram reprovados.
**A sua resposta é a solução que eu buscava!**
Muitíssimo obrigado!

Comment: @CarlosFilgueiras Que bom que deu certo, poderia marcar a resposta do Fernando [como resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104)?

Comment: @CarlosFilgueiras, que bom que ajudou. Você poderia marcar a resposta como aceita?

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi corretamente, você quer saber em porcentagem a nota de acordo com o intervalo (span).

Isto é muito utilizado em instrumentação, em que há vários valores diferentes, com unidades diferentes, portanto os valores são convertidos para porcentagem e depois os cálculos são realizados.

Todas são transformadas em porcentagem com regra de 3. Por exemplo, o intervalo é de 5 - 10, então com uma nota de 7,5, você possui 50%.

[image: Exemplo]

Portanto você pode fazer essa fórmula de regra de 3 para as três colunas, somá-las e depois dividir por 3. Assim você possui a média aritmética em porcentagem das 3 notas.

Por exemplo:

[image: Exemplo Resultado]

Em que os dados estão nas colunas E,F e G e linha 3. Então a média em porcentagem é dada pela fórmula `=((((E3-2)/(5-2))+((F3-5)/(10-5))+((G3-0)/(150-0)))/3)*100`

> Note que esta fórmula irá funcionar somente se cada intervalo possuir
>   o mesmo peso.

Comment: Daniel
Gostei, mas ocorre que pode diferença nos pesos.
A formula do Fernando parece se adequar mais ao que eu preciso.
Muitíssimo obrigado!